# Shortcut to switch between layers?

Tags: shortcut, layers

I usually use layers in Blender, as you know they are pretty handy. I have been trying to look for a shortcut to switch between layers. Any idea?

Thank you for the help,
W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the keyboard
For Top 1 to 10 Layers Press <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

[image]

and

For Bottom 1 to 10 Layers Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> and so on.

[image]

If you're are using a Laptop, Go to File -> User Preferences -> Input -> Emulate 3 Button Mouse and Emulate Numpad

[image]

Comment: What if I am using a laptop?

Comment: If your are using Laptop Go to File -> User Preferences -> Input -> Emulate 3 Button Mouse and Below Emulate Numpad

Comment: @atek Please put <kbd> formatting around the keyboard keys.

Comment: @RayMairlot Yes i have check for some key can you plz provide me key list (RMB) etc all the key if chart is available share.

Comment: @atek I am talking about formatting. Click 'edit' under your post and put <kbd> tags around the keyboard letters, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. This is so that they display as keyboard keys. Like what was done [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/93689/revisions) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/93015/revisions). Read this guide: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs