# Change between layers using shortcut in blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, layers, collections, viewlayers

I've recently update blender to 2.8 and now I'm looking for a shortcut to change quicly between layers (or collection views). Something like 2.79 had:
[Shortcut to switch between layers?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94154/shortcut-to-switch-between-layers)

I use to make presentations using full screen view (control+alt+space) and there is no way to change views there. 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Serge L](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29200/serge-l) and [Igor Svara](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/82715/igor-svara) I get to something workable. As Igor said, numbers worked but I had to create a new layer config with all the layers and just hide/unhide those that correspond with the layer config that I'm looking for.

Let's try to explain it:

My project has 8 layer configs of object within a landscape. The first one is called A1MDS (as you see in the menu). This is configured to just render some of the objects. If I put this in the menu of layers and press 1, IT WORKS but just because 1 is showing exactly the "Collection 1" objects: 
[image]

...but, if I'm in this view and press number 2...it shows nothing because my renders are configured to avoid layers in Collection 2: 
[image]

If I want to go to "view number 2" I have to do it by clicks, selecting the next view config (A1MDT) within the menu: 
[image]

So here is the solution that doesn't affect the configuration of the renders: Create a new layer config with ALL THE COLLECTIONS. I called viewport and this is very useful to go to each collection, just pressing numbers and without affecting any of the configurations for the rendering views. You can see that those "eyes" icons that represent hide or unhide are different depending on the render config (layers not rendered don't even have an "eye") and viewport config (the "eyes" are there but they are closed).

So, here is viewport pressing 1: 
[image]

And here is viewport pressing 2: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the editor type (view Layer) you can press the eye symbol of a collection while holding ctrl to isolate that collection (hide every other collection but that). Sorry I would just comment since I'm not sure that is the answer you where waiting for, but I'm not allowed to do so yet. Hope helps.

Otherwise, every collection corresponds to a number, so you can cycle through collection by pressing the numbers.

Comment: Thanks but what I need is exactly a shortcut that changes layers/collections directly from the full screen view (contro+alt+space).

Comment: I added a part, see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> +Number (optionally). This will isolate a collection.

The only drawback is that <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is supposed to undo isolation, but works only if pressed over *Outliner* area.